# Adding an item to a list

Tags: c#, list, token

In Visual Studio, how do I set attributes of a user created object?

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;

namespace SimpleMapDemo
{
    class MapLocation
    {
        public MapLocation()
        {
        }

        public LatLng Location;
        public BitmapDescriptor icon;
        public String Snippet;
        public String Title;
    }
}
```

I am wanting to add a list of these items and I have done the following code:

```
private List<MapLocation> MapLocationList = new List<MapLocation>();
MapLocation MapLocationItem = new MapLocation();
MapLocationItem.Title = "Title";
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
```

May I please have some help?

Comment: Use the constructor or the [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) syntax.

Comment: Show the surrounding code of those three lines.

Comment: @CodeCaster: according to the compiler error i assume it's in the body of the class itself.

Comment: It should be clear that one cannot access instances directly in the body.

Comment: @Tim the class `MapLocation` is shown, I don't believe OP wants to instantiate one inside the same class. As you can see in my deleted answer, I do indeed believe that the three lines are pasted in some other class, hence my question. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set properties. Do something like following:

```
class MapLocation
    {
        public MapLocation()
        {
        }

        public LatLng Location {get; set;}
        public BitmapDescriptor icon {get; set;}
        public String Snippet {get; set;}
        public String Title {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the constructor or the [collection/object initializer syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx), here are both ways:

```
class MapLocation
{
    // constructor
    public MapLocation()
    {
        MapLocationList = new List<MapLocation>();
        MapLocation MapLocationItem = new MapLocation();
        MapLocationItem.Title = "Title";
        MapLocationList.Add(MapLocationItem);
    }

    // collection initializer
    private List<MapLocation> MapLocationList = new List<MapLocation>()
    {
          // object initializer
          new MapLocation
          {
            Title = "Title"
          }
    };

    public string Title{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access (thus assign or retrieve from) your instance (called `MapLocationItem`) in the class body. This is only possible when you are in a constructor, function, getter or setter (probably I forget one or two).

```
class MainClass
{
    // Define the list of map locations in the body of the class
    // It is private thus only available from within the class itself
    // Added underscore '_' to it that is quite common for private mmebers
    private List<MapLocation> _mapLocationList = new List<MapLocation>();

    public MainClass()
    {
        // Create an instance of the MapLocation, only valid within the constructor scope
        MapLocation item = new MapLocation();
        // Set the property of the instance
        item.Title = "Title";

        // Adds the MapLocation instance 'item' to the list of MapLocations
        _mapLocationList.Add(item);
    }
}
```